# Why can't my jailbroken iPhone connect to a wifi network?

Tags: ios, wifi, jailbreak, iphone

I have an iPhone 3G 16GB with iOS 4.0.2 and my wifi is not working, I tried to fix it with reset network settings and other quick fixes like that but it still doesn't work. Sometimes it sees wifi networks but I can't connect. I don't think is a hardware problem because I can see the wifi MAC address on the device.

**Version:** 4.0.2 (8A400) (jailbreak with redsnow)
**Modem Firmware:** 05.13.04

PS: On 3.1.2 the same thing. (jailbreak with blackrain)

**Downgraded at 3.1.2, again...still nothing (jailbreak with redsnow)**

Comment: Have you ever been able to connect to a WLAN at all? Or did you never succeed?

Comment: And what are the specs on the WiFi network you want to connect to? (i.e security)

Comment: Yes, I`ve been able to connect before but now it can't find any network (not from home or office, sometimes it does but it says something like "unable to connect") I had 3.1.2 before, 2 hours ago 4.0.2 now I have 3.1.2 again jailbreak with redsnow same thing. I can see the wifi mac address so I guess is not a hardware problem (once again sometimes sees the networks but it can't connect) 
@Thomas is not the security, I disabled it nothing, with WPA nothing, router reset, iphone network reset still nothing...

Comment: Was the iPhone already jailbroken when you successfully connected to your router?

Comment: Yes it was, with blackrain and after 5 days or so, dead.

Comment: So currently, you're on 3.1.2, correct? When you downgraded, did you use a stock firmware, or did you just put the redsn0w image on there right away?

Answer (score 1):

It may still be a hardware issue -- I had [a similar problem](https://superuser.com/questions/68680/iphone-3g-cant-see-any-wifi-networks-ever) last year. But since you say that your phone sometimes does *see* a wifi network, there's hope that the hardware is okay.

First, follow the comments posted here to make sure you're running a completely normal OS without any hacks or modifications.

Then, here's Apple's description of [how to reset the network settings](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1559).

Lastly, if it still won't work, check my link above.

Comment: Resent wont work. I already did a network reset, then a full reset same thing...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that many users of 3G experienced the same problem with WIFI when uphgraded to iOS 4

Perhaps [some of the solutions listed here would help](http://appletoolbox.com/2010/06/no-iphone-wi-fi-after-ios-4-0-update-fix). In you case you are probably left with the the last option

> **Restore, but not from a backup.** One less-than-ideal fix for this issue
>   involves restoring the iPhone as a new
>   device rather than from a backup. It
>   appears that bad holdover data from
>   iPhone backups can cause loss of data
>   access. Restoring as a new phone will
>   delete contacts and other data, but
>   generally resolves this problem.
>
> To do so, connect your iPhone or iPod
>   touch to your computer, click
>   “Restore” in iTunes, then choose
>   “setup as new phone.”

Comment: I already did that, nothing. I downgraded from 4.0.2 to 3.1.2 same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try a stock (un-jailbroken) ipsw file from scratch. Use [this](http://www.ihackintosh.com/2009/07/irecovery-iphone-recovery-mode-loop-restart/) procedure to downgrade properly.

I think that when you restore using your jailbroken image, you're just putting the problem back onto to the device. I've noticed that even after a brick, when I restore with redsn0w, it's not a clean install, as my previous applications and settings are still there. I think a fresh install of stock firmware may help. Jailbreak it only after you find out if original firmware works.

Comment: I restored with original (stock).

Comment: Hmm.....I'll keep researching and let you know if I find anything new

Comment: Yesterday when I tried again to see if it finds any network, it did (my home wifi) but guess what my internet did not work lol, but the device successfully connected 3 times, when I tried the 4th time it did not work anymore... This is some weird...

Comment: It seems there is something, something that you wont believe...
Here's the solution:
You need one ****ed up iphone, one refrigerator.
Take the iphone put it in the refrigerator (a/c) leave it for 5 minutes, and wow...it works. And I'm not making any jokes.

But there`s a problem, when the iphone get's some heat again...boom no wifi (again) So is a heating issue, if you guys know any permanent fixes to that let me know. (like making some small holes in the back of the device, i'm kidding now).

Comment: LOL! Man, take it to the Apple Store

Comment: It worked, I mean it. We don't have something like that in Romania... Just resellers and they suck. It seems that the wireless chip is fried... The a/c "fix" works only till the device get's heat again. (I just wanted to test the heat possibility and I was right.)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is going to settings / General / reset / reset all settings

Good luck, mine jumped back to what it was like about a month ago then it worked fine from there!